# $http.get does not return a value

Tags: c#, json, angularjs, model-view-controller

I am going to retrieve messages received from HttpResponseMessage and present to web clients via an alert.

```
  myApp.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.saverequest = function (id) {

        $http.get('/auth/authenticated').then(function (res) {
            $scope.isAuthenticated = res.data.authenticated;

            if ($scope.isAuthenticated === false) {
                return;
            } 

            var params = {
                id: id
            };

            $http.get('/myController/saverequest', { params: params })
                .success(function (result) {
                    alert(result.message);

                }).error(function (result) {
                    alert(result.message);

            });
        });
    };

});
```

This request is sent to the controller and the message is retrieved in the backend perfectly. But, it is not returned to the  $http.get request.

```
[HttpGet("saverequest")]
public JsonResult SaveRequest(string id)
 {
    Message m = new Message();
    try
    {
        //Do something and get HttpResponseMessage ...

        m.Message = "Request saved successfully...";
    }
    catch (ApiCommunicationException e)
    {
        //Retreive errors and create a message
        m.Message = "An error from HttpResponseMessage";
    }
    return Json(new
    {
        message = m.Message
    });

}
```

Comment: what error do you have ?

Comment: I don't get any error. The alert does not pop up

Comment: try to use for example postman and ping to /myController/saverequest to see if the problem is on backend or front end ?

Comment: What version of angular? `success` and `error` were deprecated. inspect actual requests in browser dev tools network also

Comment: I see no error in the backend and I can generate the json message perfectly. I think there is a miscommunication in the $http.get

Comment: @charlietfl I use version 1.5.0. I also tried then() but the same situation occurs.

Comment: So are requests being made in dev tools network? If so is data as expected and status ok?

Comment: @charlietfl The console is empty in the dev tool.

Comment: Not the console...the network tab. It shows every request made within the page and you can filter the xhr requests and then inspect the closely

Comment: It says XHR failed loading : Get

Comment: What is status.... can get a  lot more information from there than just `failed`. The status is important to try to sort out what is failing. If not familiar what various startus codes mean can easily look them up. Can also look at payloads to see what is in them